# Can anyone discover an error in this program( finding the number of same elements in 2 generic stacks)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack

this is a problem from the algorithms and data structures course in my university, and it is as follows :

Write a function(presjek) that receives 2 generic stacks and finds the number of elements which are the same in both of them, and return it.

I already know about the trivial solution, so it's out of the question.

Here is my code:

```
int presjek(NizStek<T> s1, NizStek<T> s2){


    int br = 0;
    while(true){

        if( s1.vrh() < s2.vrh()) {s1.skini();  }
        else if(s1.vrh() > s2.vrh()) {s2.skini(); }
        else if( s1.vrh() == s2.vrh()){
            br++;
            s1.skini();
            s2.skini();

        }

        if((s1.brojElemenata() == 0) || (s2.brojElemenata() == 0)) break;
    }


    return br;
}
```

additional info:
function vrh returns the element at the top of the stack

function skini removes the top element

function brojElemenata returns the number of elements in a stack

Stacks are implemented as dynamic arrays

I've tested it on the following example:
stack 1: A C D F 
stack 2: B C D E F G
so it should return 3, but it returns 0.

Ideas?

Comment: Really, you should give your names meaningful english names (or at least explain what they are) if you want some help. I am not willing to learn Czech (or whatever is it) to answer your issues.

Comment: Oh, and learn to use a debugger to step through your code and see what is really happenning.

Comment: Are you adding the **same** objects to each stack, or just equivalent ones? Also, this looks designed for sorted stacks only, is this intentional?

Comment: I'm sorry about the names, I' new here and I thought the additional info provided would suffice to understand.
Yes, both stacks are sorted(with top element being the minimum)
And yes, only objects of the same type can be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would rewrite the function loop the following way

```
while ( ( s1.brojElemenata() != 0 ) && ( s2.brojElemenata() != 0 ) )
{

    if ( s1.vrh() < s2.vrh() ) 
    {
        s1.skini();  
    }
    else if ( s1.vrh() > s2.vrh() ) 
    {
        s2.skini(); 
    }
    else 
    {
        br++;
        s1.skini();
        s2.skini();
    }
}
```

As for your problem then you should check the copy constructor of class NizStek. Are you sure that inside the function s1.brojElemenata() and s2.brojElemenata() are not equal to zero?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I didn't get your hint at copy constructor, and I checked the code, and it's working as intented(I guess)

Comment: You should check that ( s1.brojElemenata() != 0 ) && ( s2.brojElemenata() != 0 ) BEFORE the loop. I pointed out the copy constructor because the problem is not in the function. You should check what the function accepts as its arguments inside the function. Or maybe the problem in other member functions as for example skini()

Comment: I've just retested the skini() function, it is working properly, so the problem must me the constructor, but I can't figure it out :(
It updates everything, does everything it should be doing, as are all the functions, I just retested every function. I'm sorry I'm quite useless :(

Comment: There is nothing difficult. Insert printing of the condition  ( s1.brojElemenata() != 0 ) && ( s2.brojElemenata() != 0 ) before the loop and inseide the loop after if_else statements and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but the problem wasn't actually in the functions, but rather the stupidest of all: I entered the elements in the wrong order so s2.skini() was never done. Your advice really helped me Vlad, can I upvote or +rep or something?